# Build docker image on fargate Jenkins agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-fargate

I have deployed an ECS fargate Jenkins cluster similar to this solution https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-a-serverless-jenkins-environment-on-aws-fargate/

There will be two kind of piplelines running

1. Building application docker Images
2. Everything else e.g. infra deploy etc.

For option 1 above i.e. building application docker Image, its docker in docker situation. I know using [Kaniko](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/building-container-images-on-amazon-ecs-on-aws-fargate/)  is an option but it gets very complicated.

So I tried following plugins instead so that I can use alternate options/agents to build docker images and avoid docker in docker situation.

1. [EC2 ephemeral agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2/)
2. [Codebuild Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-codebuild/)
3. [Codebuilder plugin](https://github.com/lsegal/jenkins-codebuilder-plugin)

They all work fine and satisfy my requirement **but** they all require using AWS Access Keys in Jenkins  [Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80A5A.png), which kind of is an anti-pattern and customer I am deploying this solution for might not accept putting IAM User access keys in Jenkins. IAM roles instead of AWS access keys can't be used as Jenkins Controller is a fargate container. Not sure, what to do in this situation.

Any help to solve this conundrum will be much appreciated.